# How to set vertical center of label and btn-group Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to align others elements with bootstrap `btn-group`?

```
<div class="btn-toolbar text-center">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope " style="font-size:1.5em;"></span>
        <label>Title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right">
        <a href="#" title="Open" class="btn btn-default clear-filter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Print" class="btn btn-default clear-filter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Edit" class="btn btn-default clear-filter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This how looks like, I want to text and icon would be inline.

[image: Sample image]

**EDIT:**

Now text are inline with buttons but icon aren't.

```
<div class="pull-left">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope " style="line-height: 30px; font-size: 1.5em; vertical-align: middle;"></span>
    <label style="line-height:30px;">Title</label>
</div>
```

[image: Samlpe image]

Comment: Try `span { vertical-align: middle; }`

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't works.

Comment: Also I tried to add upper case property for span. Glyphicon is font, make some logic, but don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Adding a span to your label solves most of the problem by aligning label and glyphicon. I guess this is what you wanted.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar text-center">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope " style="line-height: 30px; font-size: 1.5em; vertical-align: middle;"></span>
        <span style="line-height: 30px; font-size: 1.5em; vertical-align: middle;"><label>Title</label></span>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right">
        <a href="#" title="Open" class="btn btn-default clear-filter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Print" class="btn btn-default clear-filter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Edit" class="btn btn-default clear-filter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hesy5715/).